# Adding text to Datagrid

Tags: vb6

I need to add data in datagrid by using a button but without using a database. Just add textdata in a Datagrid.

Like this

```
text1.text="Hi"
```

It will display in datagrid column  "hi!"

How i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGrid1.Columns(<column index>) = "Hello, world!"
```

Comment: how a bout i add multiple text sir how? if i add new it will add in next row? thanks for reply sir

Comment: Set the `Row` property to determine which row to use.

Comment: the thing sir is how i'm just a beginner sorry sir i dont know how